# Why wget -O is returning in just one line?

Tags: json, linux, web-services, wget

I´m acessing a service that return a json file using HTTP protocol. The command line is:

```
wget -O /home/carlos/answer.json -a /home/carlos/logs/log_wget$hoje.log $requis
```

hoje is a string with a date: "2023-04-10"
requis contains the sites comands and variables.
Using the same line on the browser the answer is correct, with returns between the tags.
I´ve looked at Goole for this error without success.

Im using a linux machine and this command line is inside a bash shell script, (.sh)

Why the file answer.json is being created in just one line without return between the labels?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Why the file answer.json is being created in just one line without
> return between the labels?

This is probably how server is returning it, some browser do so-called *pretty printing*, for example in Firefox [JSON viewer](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/json_viewer/index.html) is used when showing JSON response.

> using a linux machine

Then I suggest trying [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for pretty print in command, it can much more than that, but for your task simple query of `.` (everything) should work, consider following example, if you have `answer.json` file holding following content

```
{"A":"Able","B":"Baker","C":"Charlie"}
```

then

```
jq '.' answer.json
```

gives output

```
{
  "A": "Able",
  "B": "Baker",
  "C": "Charlie"
}
```